# Does this sequence contain a nonnegative number?

Tags: gr.group-theory, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, sequences-and-series

Let $G$ be a (discrete) torsion free group with identity $e$. Recall that for an element $\alpha=\sum a_gg$ in $\mathbb C[G]$ (complex functions on $G$ with compact support), $\alpha^*$ is defined to be $\sum\bar{a_g}g^{-1}$ and for $\beta=\sum b_gg\in\mathbb C[G]$, we have the (convolution) product $\alpha\beta:=\sum a_gb_hgh$. Let $\alpha=\alpha^*$ be an element in $\mathbb C[G]$, define $F(\alpha):=a_e-\sum_{g\neq e}|a_g|$. Consider the sequence $(A_n)$ defined by 
$$A_n:=F\left(\alpha^{2n}\right)\quad(n\in\mathbb N)$$
Does the sequence $(A_n)$ contain a nonnegative number?

Comment: According to your  definition, $F(g)=-1$, yes? So $F(g^{2n}=-1$. Am I missing some thing?

Comment: @AliTaghavi I think you did not note the condition $\alpha=\alpha^*$.

Comment: Yes. I  am sorry.

Comment: What is the origin of this function? Is  it a  trace?Can one extend it to the  (reduced) C*  group algebra?

Comment: Let $G$ be the additive grp of the integers and $\alpha$ the fnc $\mathbf Z \to \bf C$ mapping $1$ to $i$, $-1$ to $-i$, and $\mathbf Z \setminus \{\pm 1\}$ to $0$. Then it seems to me that $\alpha = \alpha^*$ and $\alpha^2$ is the fnc $\mathbf Z \to \bf C$ with support in $\{0, \pm 2\}$ sending $0$ to $2$ and $\pm 2$ to $-1$. So $F(\alpha^2) = 2 - 2 \ge 0$.

Comment: @SalvoTringali  Yes but what about F_2 the  free group on two generators x, y and $\alpha=x+x^{-1}_Y+Y^{-1}$?

Comment: @AliTaghavi I don't know, I was just trying to answer the question in the OP. Also, I'm not sure I can interpret the notation of your comment. What does $x_Y^{-1}$ stand for? Is $Y$ a misprint for $y$?

Comment: @SalvoTringali  Ah  I am sorry  I meant  $x+x^{-1}+y+y^{-1}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No in general. If $G$ is an infinite cyclic group generated by $g$, and $\beta=1 +g+1/g$, the sum of coefficients of $\beta^{2 n}$ equals $9^n$, and the coefficient of 1 is $9^n$ times the probability that a symmetric random walk with steps $0,\pm 1$ ends up in the origin after $2n$ steps. This probability tends to 0. Thus certain large power $\alpha=\beta^N$ is a counterexample.

Comment: It is not needed to consider that $G$ is a cyclic group!